# Spring RestTemplate receives “401 Unauthorized”

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have a rest get API which is consuming in my one of the other application when I invoke the consumed API am getting entity and when I use the API in

Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/localdeal] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized: [

## 401 Unauthorized

You need a valid user and password to access this content.

]] with root cause

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized: [

## 401 Unauthorized

You need a valid user and password to access this content.

and it works fine on multiple hits any suggestions why

```
  @PostMapping(value = "/psRequestController")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getAllLocationByUser(
            @RequestBody UserLookupInformation userLookupInformation) {
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        ResponseEntity<FinancialTx[]> response =
                restTemplate.getForEntity(
                        userFxRequestUrl + userLookupInformation.getUserEmail(),
                        FinancialTx[].class);
        List<VendorDto> vendors =
                vendorService.getAllLocationByLocationAndUserValidation(
                        userLookupInformation.getLatitude(), userLookupInformation.getLongitude());
        FinancialTx[] financialTx = response.getBody();
        if (financialTx.length >= 1 && financialTx.length != 0 && vendors.size() > 0) {
            return new ResponseEntity(vendors, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else if (vendors.size() <= 0 && financialTx.length >= 1) {
            result.put(
                    "message",
                    "Oops! Looks like there is no deal available from any nearby vendor.");
            return ResponseEntity.status(NO_LOCAL_DEAL_FOUND).body(result);
        }
        result.put(
                "message",
                "Sorry! You need to have an active parking session in the last "
                        + psValidationDays
                        + " days to access deals from nearby vendors.");
        return ResponseEntity.status(NO_PARKING_SESSION_FOUND).body(result);
    
    }
```

Comment: This means the API have authorised access and you will need to pass an "Authorization" header with request you trying to make.

Comment: it's an authentication error, you are not passing username and password.